# code snippet and Behaviour of Arrow function and Normal function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Can anyone help me understand the output of the below small es6 program?

I know the difference between arrow function and normal function.

**The Arrow** function runs in parent's scope.
**The Normal** function runs in its own scope.

PFB the programme that's confusing me.

```
function Temp(){
  this.x =99;
  y =88;
  var z =77;

  setTimeout(function(){console.log(this.y+"::",this.x,"--",this.z),5});
  setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.y+"||",this.x,"--",this.z),5});

  doit(function (){ console.log(this.y+":",this.x,"_",this.z);})
  doit(()=>{console.log(this.y+"|",this.x,"-",this.z);});

  function doit(task){
    this.i =0;
    task();
  }
}

new Temp();
```

***Output***

```
88:: undefined --undefined 
undefined|| 99 --undefined 
88: undefined -undefined 
undefined| 99-undefined
```

***es6 Playground***

[es6console link](https://es6console.com/jnggv8d9/)
Wanted to know the association between variable declaration and function (arrow/normal).

Comment: So what exactly is the question :)

Comment: Try strict mode (that you always should use) and `y =88` will throw the appropriate error. As well as accessing properties on an undefined `this`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not declaring a variable (e.g. not using this.y or one of `const`, `let` and `var`) it is attached to the global scope (for browsers that is `window`).

When you call an anonymous function, it uses the global scope (`window`).

I added comments on your code.

```js
function Temp() {
  this.x = 99; // local scope
  y = 88; // global scope (attached on window as it is not declared)
  // this.y is never

  setTimeout(function() { // Scope is window/global
    console.log('log1', this.y + ":::", this.x)
  }, 5);

  setTimeout(() => { // Scope is Temp
    console.log('log2', this.y + "||", this.x)
  }, 5);

  doit(function() { // Because it is an anonymous function
                    // the scope is now that of window
    console.log('log3', this.y + ":", this.x);
  })
  doit(() => { // Arrow function: the scope of Temp
    console.log('log4', this.y + "|", this.x);
  });

  function doit(task) {
    this.i = 0;
    task();
  }
}

new Temp();
```

So to recap: Always declare variables using `const` or `let`. Also for better understanding, use the new `class` syntax. It is just a syntax sugar, but still helps to make your code better understandable.

Comment: made a small edit to the question can you look again. comments you made regarding the declaration of "y" is really helpful. though one doubt if "y" is declared with-in global scope then it should be accessed by arrow function. shouldn't it?